# How to compare "from" and "to" time fields in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql

How to compare "from" and "to" time fields in Postgres?

Suppose one record in my table that has `12:00:00` in `from` field and `18:00:00` in the "to" field.

Now if I create a new record with value `12:00:00` in the `from` field and value the value `13:00:00`  in the `to` field, it should show already exist because 12 to 13 exist in 12 to 18. Means prevent user to create a duplicate record with from and to time values.

```
create SEQUENCE transport_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE transport (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('transport_id_seq'::regclass),
  "from_time" time(6),
  "to_time" time(6)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an [exclusion constraing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) using [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html).

There is no pre-defined range type for the `time` data type, but it can easily be created:

```
create type timerange as range (
    subtype = time
);
```

With that range type, you can define an exclusion constraint that prevents overlapping times using:

```
alter table transport add constraint unique_time_range
  exclude using gist (timerange(from_time, to_time) with &&);
```

If the following row is present in the table:

```
insert into transport (from_time, to_time) 
values (time '12:00', time '18:00');
```

then this insert will fail:

```
insert into transport (from_time, to_time) 
values (time '12:00', time '13:00');
```

with the error:

> ```
> ERROR: conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "unique_time_range"
>    Detail: Key (timerange(from_time, to_time))=([12:00:00,13:00:00)) conflicts with existing key (timerange(from_time, to_time))=([12:00:00,18:00:00)).
> ```